# passing ArrayList type at the run time to more than one ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

Suppose i have following method .

```
public void abc(String className1, String className2){
List<className1> xyz=new ArrayList<className1>();
List<className2> xyz=new ArrayList<className2>();
}
```

i want to pass className that is type of ArrayList at the run time. but

```
List<className1> xyz=new ArrayList<className1>();
```

is giving error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that in Java.  You can make the method generic. `public <T> void abc(){
List<T> xyz=new ArrayList<T>();
}`

Comment: You can't do that. Closest thing you could do would be pass a generic type parameter. Generics are a compile time type safety feature, not a dynamic run-time feature (type-erasure applies to all generic types).

Comment: Please make a minimal effort to research your question before asking it.

Comment: i want to use more than one className that is i have to initialize two arrayList.

Comment: public <T> Long getAverageDays(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
  
  List<T> abc=new ArrayList<T>();    }  this  would intialize only  one list.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i didn't find any answer that why i posted my own question also my query is different !!

Comment: If you need two types, write `public <T1, T2> Long getAverageDays() { List<T1> list1 = new ArrayList<T1>(); List<T2> list2 = new ArrayList<T2>(); }`  What you can't do is pass in a `String` and try to make that a type.

Comment: thnkyu @LouisWasserman.  i also got one solution that is passing object as a list type .  List<Object> list1=new ArrayList<Object>();  which would accept any type of value and then i will typecast it into required .